# How do I connect my flask app to its heroku database using psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask

I am trying to deploy a test app that I made with Flask to Heroku.  I can't figure out what my code should look like to connect my app to the heroku postgresql database resource.  Here is my code which runs fine on my local machine.

```
import os, psycopg2, psycopg2.extras
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, 
    abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
))

def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = psycopg2.connect(database='database_name', user='username')
    return rv
```

What goes in the psycopg2.connect() parentheses? The app runs fine locally, but on the deployed app whenever I click a link that requires a database query i get an internal server error.

Comment: Are you using the right credentials for your heroku PG instance? Reminder: your connection string is defined in the `DATABASE_URL` env var, you might need to parse it for the relevant data (hostname, user, pass, port, dbname)

Comment: So rv = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL)?  I know how to find the credentials I just don't know where to put them in my code and nobody wants to give up that info.

Answer (score 1):

You would better to go with a ORM like SqlAlchemy and fetching the Heroku database connecting environment variable using os.env.get(url= , default= ) , this way you can also set the default attribute for you local database ... when deployed will use connection from Heroku ENV , when locally will use the local connection (defaulted one)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
DATABASE_DEFAULT = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/mydatabase'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', DATABASE_DEFAULT)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```